# How to find Subnets and Hosts from given IP

Tags: networking, host, subnet

I have been learning subnetting for my exam and I came through this question. 
[image]

but why it this? I first thought: `172.20.0.0` can have 254 subnets and 254 Hosts per each subnet. I obviously was wrong. can you please explain me how to get this?

thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The netmask `255.255.252.0` has 10 zero bits at the end.
`2 ^ 10` = 1024, minus a broadcast and a network address = 1022.

If you're using the [classful way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network) of dividing your network, `172.20.*` is a B network, with a 16 bit size of the network part. That gives 16-10 = 6 bits to spare, that can be split into `2 ^ 6` = 64 networks.

Comment: +1: 255.255.252.0 = 11111111 11111111 11111100 00000000

Comment: now I get it. So Hosts are calculated from netmask and subnets are calculated from network - hosts. right?